# Is there an easier way to refresh a joined CSV?

Tags: qgis, csv

I'm working with data that gets updated sporadically.  Essentially, I have a CSV which defines which postal codes belong to certain sales reps, and these postal codes might shift around.

I made multiple layers that represent different role types, that way I can switch on the layer easily.

The problem is, that if something changes.. I have to recreate the CSV Layers all over again, and then rejoin the CSV to the Shapefile layer, and then reclassify the colorings for all the sales reps.

I wish I could just hit "refresh" on the source data!  I notice in the properties it's still looking at the original file, why can't it simply reload it?

UPDATE:  I've discovered that if I set the file to "Watch" it does actually update the CSV!  However, the "Join" that I did on the Shapefile is out of date and it seems I need to delete it and manually rejoin it?  That seems unnecessary.  Any ideas?

Comment: which version of QGIS? - In 2.6 there is an option to switch off cache for delimited files - so works with changed/updated csv files.

Comment: 2.6, I turned of the cache to virtual memory.. but it won't refresh if I change the source layer that it's joining.  I have to delete the join and rejoin it

Comment: @Mapperz comment works for my setup in 2.18.6, I have a shapefile of counties in a state with a un-cached join to a csv file of crop acreage that is being 'watched'. Updating is as fast as I can refresh the render.