# Is there any way to automatically update a shp layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, update

I work with a vectorial layer (shp) created from a a CSV file which periodically changes its content.

The issue I'm raising is the following: every time I perform changes in the CSV file, I have to recreate the shp layer from the CSV, with the subsequent need to do the categorization again and change the symbols and their size.

Needless to say, I have the 'watch' option ticked when I load the CSV file. Therefore, I can see the changes in the CSV layer when I press the refresh button. But the changes do not affect the shp layer. As you could imagine, this is a real waste of time and a real nuisance and I would like to automatise the process.

I have checked [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122060/is-there-an-easier-way-to-refresh-a-joined-csv#) question out and the answers suggest switching off the cache, but I honestly don't know where that option is.

Comment: If you edit the csv and move or refresh the canvas, can you still not see the changes?

Comment: Not a real answer to your question, but two remarks on its contents:
1) you can save a csv to a shp-File (same name as before) and just append data to the shp-File
2) you can easily copy and paste legends (right click on layer)

Comment: @Joseph If I edit the csv and refresh I can see the changes into the csv layer, but not into the shp layer created from that csv.

Comment: @RudiUhl I save the csv to a shp file indeed (right button, save as ESRI shape file), but I don't know how to append the data like you say. With regard to the legends, I think it is not really useful if I have to copy and paste them every time I make a change into the csv file (roughly each 30 minutes).

Comment: @Jvr - Is your shapefile saved in a project? Could you just load the project each time you make changes to the csv? This should update the shapefile.

Comment: @Joseph Yes, it is saved in a project. Loading the project each time I make changes to the csv doesn't work. It just remains the same: the csv changes properly, but the shape doesn't change at all.

Comment: why convert the CSV to shapefile? Just style up the CSV and then it will update automaticaly.

Comment: The cache is in Settings menu > Options > Network > Cache settings.

Comment: Searching for "cache" in layer properties led me to Data Dependencies. "Correctly specifying depending layers allows QGIS to invalidate caches for this layer when the dependent layers are altered." - Quoted from data dependencies description

Comment: @IanTurton I need a shp file in order to host it in server, only shp format is supported.

Comment: @csk Thanks, I have cheked it out and it is set at "0", so I don't understand why the shp doesn't get updated when I modify the csv.
On the other hand, I have found the "Data dependencies", only in QGIS 3. I've ticked the checkbox so as to update the shp (being dependent of the csv), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, just found your mail. You can select new rows of your csv and you'll get an "append"-option once you try to overwrite your shapefile (i.e. use the same filename as before)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is the answer to your question, but anyhow.
I often regularly change a shapefile externally, in my case when working on a C++ program and effectively using QGIS as the visual part of the debugger :)
I removed and reloaded the layer often, now I simply start an editing session and close it.
Done, i.e. I get the refreshed shape. This is going to save me so much time...